# NSDateFormatter returns wrong year

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to reformat date strings I receive to another format for further use.

I get: "1.Januar 2016" which should be transformed to: 2016-01-01

My approach was to convert the original string to NSDate, then use NSDateFormatter to build the final string.

Original string:

```
NSString *originalDate = @"1.Januar 2016";
```

Convert to NSDate:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.locale=[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de_DE"];
dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"dd.MMMM yyyy";
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:originalDate];
NSLog(@"nsdate = %@", date);
```

Setup NSDateFormatters for month and year (day is irrelevant, is always "1"):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateMonthFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateMonthFormatter.locale=[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de_DE"];
dateMonthFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
dateMonthFormatter.dateFormat=@"MM";

NSDateFormatter *dateYearFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateYearFormatter.locale=[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de_DE"];
dateYearFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
dateYearFormatter.dateFormat=@"YYYY";

NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-01",[dateYearFormatter stringFromDate:date], [dateMonthFormatter stringFromDate:date]];

NSLog(@"date = %@", finalString);
```

Sadly I get this result:

```
2015-08-21 14:36:05.189 Test[315:63610] nsdate = 2016-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
2015-08-21 14:36:05.194 Test[315:63610] date = 2015-01-01
```

The year is 1 behind. This only happens in January, no other month.

I guess it's a problem with the time zone, but then I don't get why only the year is behind, not the month.

Comment: Problem solved, thank you very much.

Comment: How you solved this issue?

Answer (score 12):

You should use `yyyy`, not `YYYY`.

Comment: From the [Date Format Table](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table), the `YYYY` is "Year (in 'Week of Year' based calendars). Normally the length specifies the padding, but for two letters it also specifies the maximum length. This year designation is used in ISO year-week calendar as defined by ISO 8601, but can be used in non-Gregorian based calendar systems where week date processing is desired. May not always be the same value as calendar year." Bottom line, use `YYYY` for week of the year formatting, but otherwise use `yyyy`.